# How do I keep my Editor from scrolling below keyboard when moving the cursor?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've got an Editor which is tall enough to accommodate multiple lines of input. The editor is at the bottom of the screen if it matters. Once multiple lines are entered, if you move the cursor up a line, the entire view shifts downward, so the line you just left is now obscured by the keyboard. I'd like it to not do this unless the line the cursor is on is either off screen or close to being off screen. Sort of like how the built in Android message app works. Here's what I mean in pictures.

[image]

1. Default state, everything looks good. We have 3 lines of input

[image]

2. I move the cursor up one line: notice that the entire view has shifted down one line and so "line 3" is now obscured. I don't want this behavior (it among other things hides some UI elements).

[image]

3. This is the Android messaging app. This is the behavior I want: when you move the cursor to that next line, the view doesn't just shift downward. If you have enough lines to scroll past the visible area, Android just shifts the text and not the entire view to accommodate it.

In essence, I just want the contents of the editor to shift (when appropriate) and not the entire window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Firstly, in MainActivity.cs, after the LoadApplication call, I added this:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

Using the default or .Pan didn't work at all. Note that just doing this didn't fix the issue. I also had to take the class that's described [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/) and use it. Without that class, things didn't work correctly. Also the "alternative method" described on that page didn't work (which was basically just changing the soft input mode adjust).

In the event that the link I mentioned dies, here's the class. I did slightly modify it so that by default **it is not enabled**. You just set `Disabled = false` on it to enable it. Also you call the static method *Init* to initialize the class.

```
public class AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid
    {

        private readonly View _childOfContent;
        private readonly FrameLayout.LayoutParams _frameLayoutParams;
        private int _usableHeightPrevious;

        public static AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid Instance { get; private set; }

        private bool _disabled = true;
        public bool Disabled
        {
            get => _disabled;
            set
            {
                if (_disabled != value)
                {
                    _disabled = value;
                    if (_disabled)
                        _childOfContent.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout -= PossiblyResizeChildOfContent;
                    else
                        _childOfContent.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += PossiblyResizeChildOfContent;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Init(Activity activity)
        {
            if (Instance != null)
                return;

            Instance = new AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(activity);
        }

        private AndroidBug5497WorkaroundForXamarinAndroid(Activity activity)
        {
            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
            _childOfContent = content.GetChildAt(0);            
            _frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)_childOfContent.LayoutParameters;
        }

        private void PossiblyResizeChildOfContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int usableHeightNow = ComputeUsableHeight();
            if (usableHeightNow != _usableHeightPrevious)
            {
                var usableHeightSansKeyboard = _childOfContent.RootView.Height;
                var heightDifference = usableHeightSansKeyboard - usableHeightNow;

                _frameLayoutParams.Height = usableHeightSansKeyboard - heightDifference;

                _childOfContent.RequestLayout();
                _usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
            }
        }

        private int ComputeUsableHeight()
        {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            _childOfContent.GetWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            return (r.Bottom - r.Top);
        }
```